# How to make the normal way of Routes with hash keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, routes

Now I can see my received message by accessing to `example.com/messages/46747`

and My routes are set set like this

```
'messages/:id' => 'messages#show', :as => 'show_messages'
```

The link tag to access that page is set like

```
<%= link_to 'show message', show_messages_path %>
```

In this case, the IDs of the messages are shown in the URL.
I guess that IDs should be taken place by hash keys in most cases.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. To access your message ID from the controller all you can simply use: `params[:id]`.

Comment: Sorry about my poor explanation. What I want to do is hiding message id that is shown in URL as one of parameters.

Comment: You're going to have to show some kind of an ID, otherwise it won't be very RESTful, and users won't be able to link to it. Unless message is a single resource per user and not a collection (in this cause you could use the `resource` keywork). In other words, what would you like the URL to look like? `example.com/messages/show`, or `example.com/messages/MSG_NAME`?

Comment: I wanted to make the url something like messages/show/hd348h2jj34104federk4   this kind of hash key type. This is not normal in rails??? do you guys always want like this messages/show/3246 ?

Comment: You can add a Unique Identifier (UID) for each message. but a better way would be to use some sort of an authentication mechanism such as devise (see: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/)

Answer (score 3):

Use ActiveRecord::Base to_param in order to change the url generated by the path:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```

Just override the to_param method in Message class by the text you'd like to see in the url.

Comment: Thanks:) it would work for user type. but what if it was message??? Messages are being made like hundreds in a minutes. I'd like to prevent user to access to someone else's message by typing it directly  to URL. something like messages/show/82358357

Comment: Preventing user access to others' messages should be done with authentication restrictions.

Comment: So you mean it really doesn' matter if the URL is something like messages/show/324732732 ???

Comment: In the context of preventing unauthorized access not. It is only a cosmetic change to the url.

Comment: That's true. Okay, I will leave it how it is :)